# Get cell ids from Sumproduct function in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, range

I need to select cells that matches 3 criteria in 3 ranges.

Sumproduct does the job but I need to know the cells that are selected not the result.

Is there any othe function that works like same.

Function I'm using

```
SUMPRODUCT((Range_one=F2)*(Range_two=F3)*(Range_three=F4))
```

All I need is to get those cells indivisually.

Comment: What do you mean by "select cells" - formulas can't select cells? It would help if you show us some sample data and your expected output. Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Functions can't select cells. You need VBA coding then.